# Some small problem with strings, arrays and foreach

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach

```
<?php


$ep_place = 'Arugghh!';    

$eps_array = array();

$eps_array[] = $ep_place;

foreach($eps_array[1] as $eps_match)
{ 

$argh = $eps_match;

echo $argh;
}

?>
```

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What is it that I doing wrong here..?! I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping over the second element of $eps_array, which is wrong.

Change your foreach to:

> foreach($eps_array as $eps_match) { }

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to be it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ep_place = 'Arugghh!';    

$eps_array = array();

$eps_array[] = $ep_place;

foreach($eps_array as $eps_match)
{ 

$argh = $eps_match;

echo $argh;
}
```

You should use array in foreach but not element of array

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to be it!